# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

**As the title, when i use sqlalchemy create_engine to connect mysql the error occur.**

Thanks in advance.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/jedoreclub')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 56, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 139, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 218, in load
    (self.group, name))
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql
```

Comment: What SQLAlchemy version are you using? Have you installed one of the required [DBAPI drivers](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#dialect-mysql)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä SQLAlchemy 1.1.9
i installed the mysql-python

Comment: You're using a rather old version of Python (2.6). What do you get, if you try to `import pkg_resources`? What version of `setuptools` you have installed?

Comment: @IljaEverilä `import pkg_resources` is normal. setuptools version is 0.6.

Comment: python 2.6 is preinstalled in centos 6.9, if upgrade it, some unpredicatable error may occur.

Comment: I'm getting the similat kind of error for teradata. Any ideas how to solve it?

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

Comment: @Ramsey origin question is about mysql, but for your question take a look here https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata/issues/37

Comment: I tried that process, but no luck

Comment: This can also happen when you're using an unsupported value in the URI, for example, psql:// instead of postgres://   -- I add that since this is the first result that appears when searching for that error.